# Script de automatización de proceso (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, linux, date, script

He probado a hacer un script para que me automatice un proceso para todos los lunes y por desgracia no consigo hacerlo funcionar ya que ni me da error.

```
    #!/bin/bash
fecha=$(date -d "last Monday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
host="localhost"
usuario="root"
pass="1234"
database="sipmanager"
args_sql="-h$host -u$usuario -p$pass -D$database -s -e"
mysql $args_sql " SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = 'outbound' AND end =$fecha;"
```

Con el código de ese modo ocurre lo siguiente:

```
# bash -x script.sh 
++ date -d 'last Monday' +%Y-%m-%d
+ fecha=2021-05-24
+ host=localhost
+ usuario=root
+ pass=1234
+ database=sipmanager
+ args_sql='-h localhost -u root -p1234 -D sipmanager -s -e'
+ mysql -h localhost -u root -p1234 -D sipmanager -s -e ' SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = '\''outbound'\'' AND end =2021-05-24;'
```

Y ahí se queda y no se como hacer para que me muestre lo que le pido.

Comment: ¿Esto funciona si lo ejecutas directamente en la línea de comandos? **`mysql -h localhost -u root -p1234 -D sipmanager -s -e ' SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = '\''outbound'\'' AND end =2021-05-24;'`**

Comment: Por otra parte, puede que la consulta no dé error, pero no arrojará resultados. Para comparar fechas debes poner comillas simples en los datos. Intenta corregir eso en el script: **`mysql $args_sql "SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = 'outbound' AND end ='$fecha';"`** Y si la columna es del tipo `DATETIME`  sólo encontrará filas si la hora de las mismas es `00:00:00`. Son cosas que debes tener siempre en cuenta.

Comment: Al ejecutarlo en la linea de comandos me manda un mensaje asi :                      
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = 'outbound' AND end =2021-05-24;'                                                                                                                             por otro lado tampoco arroja resultados, y en cuanto a la fecha lleva el formato adecuado todo esto desde la consola de mysql funciona y esta ya comprobado.

Comment: Yo no me refería al formato, sino a que el valor debía ir entre comillas simples: `'$fecha'` y si el criterio de comparación era mayor que, no igual que, de este lado no podíamos adivinarlo. Cuando un Script no funcione siempre es bueno probar aparte lo que ese Script ejecuta, en este caso, probar la consulta SQL directamente en MySQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano en cualquier caso, si lo pones entre comillas simples la variable `$fecha` no se sustituirá, sino que se pondrá el valor literal "$fecha". Haz la prueba: `s="hola"; echo '$s'; echo "$s"`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' gracias por el dato. No soy un gran conocedor de la sintaxis en Linux. Supongo que habrá alguna forma de escapar, el hecho es que en la cadena final el valor de la fecha debe quedar entre comillas simples. Si queda sin comillas nunca encontrá la fecha.

Answer (score 1):

al final lo consegui era mas simple de lo que esperaba ya que el unico fallo era cambiar el = por un > y corregir un par de comillas.

```
#!/bin/bash

fecha=$(date -d "last Monday" +"%Y-%m-%d")
host="localhost"
usuario="root"
pass="1234"
database="sipmanager"
args_sql="-h $host -u $usuario -p$pass -D $database -s -e"
mysql $args_sql " SELECT channel,sm_dst,answer,duration FROM rt_calls WHERE sm_type = 'outbound' AND end >'$fecha' INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/exp5.csv';"
```

con esto ya funciona perfecto y sin problema.